# How to set 15 min after system date using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, arrays

How to set 15 min after time from the current time set to `time` input field using jQuery.

```
<input name="user_time" id="user_time" type="time" class="form-control" >
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please elaborate. When do you want this to happen, on change of the field? On load of the page? Also jQuery will not be the main actor here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution that works. I don't know what event you want to use, but for example I have use an onclic even on your input.

```
$('#user_time').click(function(){
        var d = new Date(); 
    var min = d.getMinutes() + 15
        var date = d.getHours()+":"+ min;
    $('#user_time').val(date);
});
```

Change the event and use the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. create a new `Date` object: `let d = new Date();`
2. add 15 minutes: `d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 15);`
3. define the new value: `let user_time = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();`
4. set the new value with jQuery: `$('#user_time').val(user_time);` (or you can simply do it with Vanilla JS: `document.getElementById('user_time').value = user_time;`)

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 15);
let user_time = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
$('#user_time').val(user_time); // document.getElementById('user_time').value = user_time;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="user_time" id="user_time" type="time" class="form-control" >
```